# How do users like Anon get their accounts deleted?

Tags: discussion

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting?rq=1) has **2925** up-votes at the time of this writing. How did @anon get his account deleted? The only thing I can think of is if he chose to delete his account of his own free will.

Comment: why do you ask? (nearly 7rs ago now!)

Answer (score 6):

There are a few ways to get one's account deleted.

1. Post spam or rude/abusive content.
2. Never post anything, so the account gets automatically deleted as unused.
3. Be under 13 years old.
4. Ask for your account to be deleted.

When you see a post (that hasn't been migrated) with a non-existent owner account, it's safe to assume that #4 happened.

However, there are two distinct reasons why you may see unlinked "anon" username.

1. "anon" is the name the system attaches to posts that were disassociated from the author at the author's request. This does not involve account deletion.
2. Until May 2011, display names of deleted users were kept. (Since then, they are reverted to userNNNNN format).

In this specific case, [Wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20090904211050/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting) shows that the post author was indeed a user named "anon". ---They also appear to have been suspended, since  the reputation is shown as 1 rep.--- TZHX pointed out that the question sat at zero score at the time of this snapshot, which explains 1 rep.

So, a plausible chain of events is that the user posted that question and nothing else, and eventually requested the deletion of their account.

Comment: They may just have asked only the one question, which had no up votes at the time, also explaining having only 1 rep. The user was deleted by March 2010 (when the question had only a single upvote) -- if the user wasn't registered, it's reasonable to assume the cookie had been deleted.

Comment: Good point about the question score. But even if the cookie was lost, the account wouldn't have been deleted as abandoned, as it has a non-deleted post. So it had to be deleted upon a request, and the user had to have control of the account in order for verify ownership at the time.

Comment: Why "When you see a post (that hasn't been migrated) with a non-existent owner account, it's safe to assume that #4 happened."? Why can't it be any of the other three things you mention? Or disassociation from the post?

Comment: @Martin if it were just disassociated then user 101825 should still exist?

Comment: @TZHX but if all you're looking at is the post and it is disassociated you shouldn't know the userid of the original poster. You would only get from the way back machine etc?

Comment: @martin yes, sorry. I didn't realise you were being more general than this specific case. Really need to wake up.